# react-native java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found. "[TypeError: Network request failed]"

Tags: android, react-native, backend

I saw similar issue on Stack Overflow but didn't find proper solution for the same. So I am posting again if anybody has any idea, Please answer.

Problem happens on Android only on iOS it is working fine. It says error:

> "[TypeError: Network request failed]".

I used Axios as well native fetch method but getting same error in both ways to access the Web API.

Comment: Have you added network configuration file in manifest as shown in this documentation 
https://developer.android.com/privacy-and-security/security-config

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Client is not ready to share the certificate for security reason. Do you have any other solution?